# Linux bridge broken after upgrade, out of ideas / places to look (now 4.20.0-arch1-1-ARCH) (works in 4.19.13)

Tags: linux, bridge

UPDATE:

After stepping away from the problem for a little bit I realized there was one thing that I could examine or test which I hadn't.

Reverting to an older version of Linux allowed me to work-around the issue, BUT still importantly raises the question: What's missing to make this work for newer versions of Linux?

Linux nas 4.19.13-1-lts #1 SMP Sun Dec 30 07:38:47 CET 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Orig:

The Question: **What else should I check to try and isolate and fix this so that bridged networking to LXC 'vm's work again?**

For debugging this problem, I've disabled normal LXC container startup.  Instead I'm running them manually with additional logging.

lxc-start --logfile=/var/log/lxc/debug.$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).log --logpriority=DEBUG -F -n containername

LAN hosts can ping/talk to HOST
HOST can ping/talk to LAN hosts

Two different traces

On the bridge: as expected

```
tcpdump -pi bridge port 67 or port 68 or icmp[icmptype] == icmp-echo or icmp[icmptype] == icmp-echoreply

(time) IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from (mac) (oui Unknown)...
```

Yet it doesn't get relayed/forwarded to the physical network device:

```
tcpdump -i bridge_IF  port 67 or port 68 or icmp[icmptype] == icmp-echo or icmp[icmptype] == icmp-echoreply
(no dhcp packets)
```

The bridge looks correct

```
# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.bridgemac          no              enpNs0
                                                        enpNs0
                                                        vethXXXXXX
```

Everything looks mostly as expected there.

```
(provided by iptables-nft)
ebtables -L
Bridge table: filter

Bridge chain: INPUT, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

Bridge chain: FORWARD, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

Bridge chain: OUTPUT, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

nft list ruleset
table bridge filter {
        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority -200; policy accept;
        }

        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority -200; policy accept;
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type filter hook output priority -200; policy accept;
        }
}
table ip filter {
        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        }

        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        }
}
```

Also sysctl and module config items.

```
# cat /etc/sysctl.d/*
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0
kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1

# lsmod | grep table
nf_tables             147456  2 nft_reject_ipv6,nft_reject
nfnetlink              16384  1 nf_tables
x_tables               49152  1 ip6t_REJECT

# cat /etc/modprobe.d/*
blacklist ip_tables
blacklist iptable_filter
blacklist iptable_nat
blacklist ip6_tables
blacklist ip6table_filter
blacklist x_tables
install br_netfilter
```

--

So far everything looks like it should work, but it isn't.

```
(container) # ip addr add x.x.x.x/y dev z
(container) # ping VMHOST
Works, ping reply.
(container) # ping ROUTER-GW
Nope, Destination Host Unreachable
```

HOWEVER, now something really unexpected happens (rather, doesn't happen).

```
(VHMOST) # ping ROUTER-GW
Nope, Destination Host Unreachable
Also, the connection to the VMHOST (often) times out at this point.
```

This last twist seems to point towards an issue in something that I haven't checked so far, I'm not sure if anything in the Linux namespaces relates to this problem.

Looking at the LXC logs don't offer anything obvious, but I copied everything that I though MIGHT have been related.  Nothing actually says it, but I do wonder if the namespaces got messed up somehow.

```
lxc-start VM TIMESTAMP.390 DEBUG    network - network.c:setup_hw_addr:2767 - Mac address "REDACTED" on "eth0" has been setup
lxc-start VM TIMESTAMP.393 INFO     conf - conf.c:mount_entry:2039 - No such file or directory - Failed to mount "/sys/fs/fuse/connections" on "/usr/lib/lxc/rootfs/sys/fs/fuse/connections" (optional)
lxc-start VM TIMESTAMP.510 INFO     utils - utils.c:lxc_mount_proc_if_needed:1239 - I am 1, /proc/self points to "1"
lxc-start VM TIMESTAMP.536 WARN     conf - conf.c:lxc_setup_devpts:1641 - Invalid argument - Failed to unmount old devpts instance
lxc-start VM TIMESTAMP.536 DEBUG    conf - conf.c:lxc_setup_devpts:1678 - Mount new devpts instance with options "gid=5,newinstance,ptmxmode=0666,mode=0620,max=1024"
lxc-start VM TIMESTAMP.537 INFO     conf - conf.c:setup_personality:1741 - Set personality to "0x0"
lxc-start VM TIMESTAMP.537 DEBUG    conf - conf.c:setup_caps:2550 - Dropped mac_admin (33) capability
lxc-start VM TIMESTAMP.537 DEBUG    conf - conf.c:setup_caps:2550 - Dropped mac_override (32) capability
lxc-start VM TIMESTAMP.537 NOTICE   conf - conf.c:lxc_setup:3745 - The container "VM" is set up

Linux salt 4.20.0-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Dec 24 03:00:40 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# pacman -Qs lxc
local/lxc 1:3.1.0-1
```

Comment: Update:

After stepping away from the problem for a little bit I realized there was one thing that I could examine or test which I hadn't.

Reverting to an older version of Linux allowed me to work-around the issue, BUT still importantly raises the question: What's missing to make this work for newer versions of Linux?

Linux nas 4.19.13-1-lts #1 SMP Sun Dec 30 07:38:47 CET 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: is ip forwarding enabled?

Comment: It works on 4.19.13 without ip forwarding as this is a BRIDGED, not a ROUTED configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, following all links from the email to make sure other people that hits this knows what to do.

Apply:
https://marc.info/?l=linux-netdev&m=154696956604748&w=2

Fixed it for me, it's to do with fq pacing

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm that applying that single line patch DOES make the difference and resolve the issue (for me).

Hopefully it's backported to the 4.20.x series.

ArchLinux had a package that made testing the a custom-kernel build easier, but it was based on 4.20.2, so I re-tested without (failed, as expected) the patch and with (appears to be working, as hoped).